# iOS 10.3 beta 1 add a slash("/") in url schema

Tags: ios

I use a *url schema* to open my App in web pages, the original *url schema* is

```
appName://article?id=xxx
```

When I click this url, it opens our App, but the string for **UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey** in the **launchOptions** dictionary is:

```
appName://article/?id=xxx
```

Is it a bug or Apple just add this slash on purpose?

Comment: It's like url scheme, e.g. "http://x.com/?x=x"

Comment: 10.3 beta 2 doesn't insert the slash.  Anyway, I don't think it's a good idea to insert the slash **for** me.  Thx.